# Extensionless PHP File via Mod_Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make a PHP file look like a folder via Mod_Rewrite...  but I have no idea how to do it.

I used to do it like this:

```
    <files store>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
    </files>

    DirectoryIndex store
```

Which was the simplest way to do it... but I changed servers and "ForceType" is not allowed...

I need to do it with Mod_ReWrite somehow...

I only want it to work on the one file not every file that ends in PHP...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(file)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Change `file.php` to whatever your file name is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if u need to append query:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /yourfile.php?&id=$1&user=$2  [NC]
```

OR this when not

```
RewriteRule ^folder /yourfile.php  [NC]
```